# how to get child type of a interface in ts

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

i'm trying to do something like a `EventBus`, now i've put all event names and event parameters in one interface like this:

```js
interface A {
   a: {
      x: number
      y: number
   }
   b: {
      name: string
   }
}
function on<T extends keyof A>(evName: T, cb: (ev, param: A[T]) => void) {}
```

it's ok to write callback function like:

```
on('a', (ev, param) => {})
```

in this part of code, `param` has a certain and correct type of `{ x: number, y: number }`,
but when i try to write the callback function in another file like:

```
// file 1
on('a', doA)

// file 2
export const doA: (ev, params: ?) = (ev, params) => {}
```

i don't know how to declare the type of function `doA()`

Comment: Why can't you use `{x: number, y: number}`?  Does `const doA: (ev: any, params: A["a"]) => void = (ev, params) => { }` not work for you?  If not, please [edit] to clarify what your issue is.

Comment: `A` is a interface, you can't use a string to index it, and use `{ x: number, y: number }` to declare the parameter of function `doA` is a little bit redundant, i've already defined all needed types in `A`, and function `doA` is only designed as a callback of event `a`, so the problem is how to get type of `params`, as the event name is certain

Comment: Are you trying to say that you don't believe `A["a"]` works?  [You can try it yourself and see that it does](https://tsplay.dev/wgB0vW).  What am I missing here?

Comment: for my project, `function showPreviewWindow(ev, param: MAP_EV_PARAMS_OF_MAIN['SHOW_PREVIEW_WINDOW']) {}` got a error like `Property 'SHOW_PREVIEW_WINDOW' does not exist on type 'MAP_EV_PARAMS_OF_MAIN'.ts(2339)`

Comment: So `A["a"]` works, but the analogous indexed access type in your project does not work?  Then you haven't presented a [mre] and we can't really do too much to help.  Maybe you can track down the discrepancy and [edit] to post a true [mre] that demonstrates the problem you're having?

Comment: i do apologize to you, what you've said does work, but i have two interface with similar names, the key i used to index the interface wasn't in the interface, and i've found another solution like `function showPreviewWindow2<T extends 'SHOW_PREVIEW_WINDOW'>(ev, param: MAP_EV_PARAMS_OF_RENDERER[T]) { }`

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of having `T extends "SHOW_PREVIEW_WINDOW"` is, since it can essentially only be that type, but ‍♂️.  What should we do here?  My suggestion of `A["a"]` is apparently acceptable, but you wrote your own answer for some reason.  If you want me to write up an answer with links to documentation about indexed access types, I can.  Or I can just disengage if you'd rather just keep your own answer (although I hope you'll add doc links).  Let me know how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: okay, i've deleted that answer. i wrote that just for trying to close this question, but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) of the form `ObjType[KeyType]` even if the `KeyType` is a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"a"` and not a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  For your example, you could just write `A["a"]` which evaluates to `{x:number; y: number}`:

```
const doA: (ev: any, params: A["a"]) => void =
  (ev, params) => { }
  //   ^? (parameter) params: { x: number; y: number; }

on('a', doA); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgLkx12QA9CQBXAWwCNpjcBPCm+qYgX2NsOxOQg41CIQDOYKKADmXLNxiUQCMMAD2IZBoA8AFWQRSkEABMxyANYQmamGgB8ACggA3AHLDRyXQBpkCXmRnF0I4ECY-AAc4KGFCVABtXQBdAEpkAF57ZBc1YBN0jGRuLA1HAHI4cr9gqJjhdKzMYtSsLAQNCWQTNVRCYNDwutjqMXiEgCI4CbTM7Nz8zOJa5GiRsUbsou5cAHpdkgA9AH4gtc9IKHTz0b4yVjpoAG5kFkE2Z+K2ssrq7t7Ui99loLHAmEA)